# Match everything between two strings that contain a third string

Tags: python, regex

To clarify the title, I am trying to find a row in an html document that is surrounded by the following string (or some close variation):

```
<!--Copy from here-->
```

and contains exactly one of a certain filename that is unique.  Let's call it `SN12345.htm`

The document I'm searching has several of these rows and I'm having a hard time isolating just one row between the 'copy' string.  The following regex is matching almost the entire document (with the single-line flag turned on):

```
\<!-+Copy [A-Za-z ]+-+\>(.*SN12345\.htm.*)\<!-+Copy [A-Za-z ]+-+\>
```

What I would like is for it to match only the first occurrence of the copy string following the file name.  How do I do this?  I'm using Python.

Here's a sample input:

```
<!--Copy from here-->
 <TR valign=top>
 <TD><A href="SN_2100-24.htm">2100-24</A></TD>
 <TD>2100 Bioanalyzer - peak find problem when using new Ambion RNA ladder Cat. #7152</TD>
 <TD>11/04</TD><td valign=top><p align="center">I</p></td></tr>
<!--Copy from here-->
 <TR valign=top>
 <TD><A href="SN_2100-23.htm">2100-23</A></TD>
 <TD>2100 Bioanalyzer communication problems when both Biosizing and 2100 Expert SW are active</TD>
 <TD>10/04</TD><td valign=top><p align="center">I</p></td></tr>
<!--Copy from here-->
 <TR valign=top>
 <TD><A href="SN_2100-22.htm">2100-22</A></TD>
 <TD>Incompatibility of 2100 Expert and Microsoft Windows XP Service Pack 2</TD>
 <TD>09/04</TD><td valign=top><p align="center">I</p></td></tr>
<!--Copy from here-->
 <TR valign=top>
 <TD><A href="SN_2100-21.htm">2100-21</A></TD>
 <TD>2100 Bioanalyzer - DNA LabChip Kits and detergent containing PCR buffer</TD>
 <TD>04/04</TD><td valign=top><p align="center">I</p></td></tr>
<!--Copy from here-->
 <TR valign=top>
 <TD><A href="SN_2100-20.htm">2100-20</A></TD>
 <TD>General PC system and settings requirements for 2100 expert software</TD>
 <TD>04/04</TD><td valign=top><p align="center">I</p></td></tr>
<!--Copy from here-->
 <TR valign=top>
 <TD>2100-19</A></TD>
 <TD>not used</TD>
 <TD>01/04</TD><td valign=top><p align="center">I</p></td></tr>
<!--Copy from here-->
 <TR valign=top>
 <TD><A href="SN_2100-18.htm">2100-18</A></TD>
 <TD>RNA 6000 Pico Kits - ART&reg; Aerosol Resistant Tips generate baseline abnormalities</TD>
 <TD  >01/04</TD><td valign=top><p align="center">I</p></td></tr>
<!--Copy from here-->
```

Comment: Please provide some sample inputs.

Comment: @revo just updated it

Comment: Try [`<!--Copy[^-]*-->(?:(?!<!--Copy[^-]*-->)[\s\S])*SN12345\.htm(?:(?!<!--Copy[^-]*-->)[\s\S])*<!--Copy[^-]*-->`](https://regex101.com/r/Yb6PDA/1)

Comment: @revo  Thanks, that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose `XX = <!--Copy[^-]*-->` and regex below:

```
XX(?:(?!XX)[\s\S])*SN12345\.htm(?:(?!XX)[\s\S])*XX
||^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^||
```

You see repeated patterns exist. Two `XX` at both ends define a boundary where match should start and end. Then there is `(?:(?!XX)[\s\S])*` which I'm going to explain:

- `(?:` Start a non-capturing group

  - `(?!XX)` A negative lookahead, following characters shouldn't be `XX`
  - `[\s\S]` If previous pattern asserts then take one step ahead
- `)*` End of group, repeat as many as possible

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/Yb6PDA/1)